# How to remove single quotation mark from a String using REGEX

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I used this below expression

```
s/^'|'$//
```

Just I am expecting the below result

`'value'` --> `value` (Without single quotation marks)

but in my expression the result is given as `value'`
it only removes the first occurrence only.
How can I fix that ?

Comment: Add `g` modifier

Comment: As was suggested, use the `g` modifier which means "globally". Otherwise, the regex replaces the first time it matches and then stops. With `g`, it continues to find and replace as many matches as it can.

Comment: Thanks lot Wiktor, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by @WiktorStribiżew and @lurker, without the `/g` modifier, the `s///` operator will only operate on the first (left-to-right) occurrence that it matches. See [perlretut](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut#Global-matching) for more info.

As an alternative it may be simpler to run it as two regexes (this is commonly done for `trim` implementations):

```
do { s/^'//; s/'$// } for $val;
```

Comment: It's simpler and less weird as two <strike>regexes</strike>substitutions, but it's faster as one.

Comment: Also, `do{}` not needed if you use comma instead of semi-colon.

Comment: Most people dislike the scalar/void context comma so I opted to show the do variant - as for efficiency, the two substitutions is far more efficient than the alternation in tests I've seen, especially on longer strings, but as always benchmarking is appropriate if it matters.

Comment: You need to search the string either way, so its length is irrelevant. The single substitution is faster because it saves one op and saves a regex engine startup (which takes relatively long).